# Is there a way to install IntenseDebate on localhost?

Tags: php, comments, wordpress, disqus

I've been searching for a while now for a solution to install IntenseDebate on my local machine. From what I've seen, there doesn't seem to be anything around that would help me do that.

Anyone has had any success installing IntenseDebate on their localhost?

Thanks folks,

LP

Comment: What have you tried?  What has failed?  Where are you experiencing problems?  Installing web-based software locally should be nearly identical to installing it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

[IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/) is comment software that is reliant on being connected to the internet, it must connect to the internet to work, so you can't have a fully local version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

I have NOT tried this, but I suppose it'll work if you use a service such as http://noip.com.

it is likely that Intense Debate must locate your machine via IP or URL as if it was hosted on an actual web host, just being able to connect to the internet will not suffice. You'll also probably need to set up your local environment so that you can use your noip.com URL as your virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got done installing Intense Debate on a local development version of a site that I'm building, which is why I found this.  In total, it took about two minutes, and it works fine.  There's apparently no difference between a local install and live install, as it's just a small javascript wrapper that you need to place in your code.  It works fine locally for me, and I'm assuming that it'll also work fine once it's moved to the live server.

Answer (score -2):

Head over to the Intense Debate home page and add your blog's URL in the box provided. Then click on the Install Intense Debate" button. Follow the instruction after.

Comment: This does not install the product on a local server.

Answer (score -3):

Go to intense debate web page, click install intense debate and follow the instruction.